# Missing webparts in Sharepoint 2013 online

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-apps, sharepoint-online

I have a problem, when i edit the page and click on, "insert webpart or app part". I cant see any webparts or app parts in the category list to the left. Its empty, only thing i see is the category, Apps.

What can it be?, I'm in the owner group aswell.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a permission issue. Add user to "Designer" group then they will be able to see full options. I just encountered the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Site Settings > Web Designer Galleries > Web parts
then Library tab > Library Settings > Permissions for this gallery and Check permissions.

You need read permission to see the Web parts.

Answer (score -1):

On the SPOnline site that I administer "Owners" don't have page edit permission.  It's possible that you need a higher permission level to do anything but make basic changes to your own page.